# Android tabbed layout/view crashing

Tags: android, tabs

I have recently started Android development, and i already know Java. So i was following
[This](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html) tutorial on the android development site about how to create a tabbed layout.
Even though i went after everything in the tutorial and eclipse prompts no errors, the application crashes when i run it on a froyo API level 8 Emulator. My application is build as well on API level 8.

What i think might cause it:
1) I seem to have a warning in the AndroidManifest.xml which i dont understand, it highlights this line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

2) In the tutorial they created a page with 3 tabs, while im using 5 tabs. maybe thats it??]

My code:

Main activity:

```
package ent.com;


import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class TestActivity extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); 
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  
    Intent intent; 

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Players.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("players").setIndicator("Players",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_players))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Staff.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("staff").setIndicator("Staff",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_staff))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, League.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("league").setIndicator("League",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_league))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Finance.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("finance").setIndicator("Finance",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_finance))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Next.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("next").setIndicator("Next Game",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_next))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
}
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="ent.com"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to mention every other activity in the manifest too.

```
<activity android:name=".Players"
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Staff"
</activity>
<activity android:name=".League"
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Finance"
</activity>
<activity android:name=".Next"
</activity>
```

an activity undeclared in the manifest can cause the app to crash.

Answer (score 0):

use some logs to see whats going wrong

```
import android.util.Log;

private static final String TAG = MainGame.class.getSimpleName();

 intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Finance.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("next").setIndicator("Next Game",
                  res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_next))
              .setContent(intent);
        Log.d(TAG, "Finance Created!!!!");
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: in the LogCat it will also log the errors that the phone does and when the phone does force clse needed is will post the logs why